# Prove that $\left|\sum_{r\neq s}u_r\overline u_s\csc\pi(x_r-x_s)\right|^2\leq\sum_{r}\left|\sum_s\overline u_s\csc\pi(x_r-x_s)\right|^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

On a paper that I'm studying, it is written, without another: "By Cauchy's inequality
$$\left|\sum_{r\neq s}u_r\overline u_s\csc\pi(x_r-x_s)\right|^2\leq\sum_{r}\left|\sum_s\overline u_s\csc\pi(x_r-x_s)\right|^2"$$
But I did not understand why this happens. I add a description of the quantities in play: $x_1, x_2,... ,x_R$ denote real numbers which are distinct modulo 1; $u_r$ is $\ell^2$ complex sequence; $\csc=\frac{1}{\sin}$.

Moreover, what happens applying Cauchy's inequality for
$$\left|\sum_{r\neq s}u_r\overline v_s\csc\pi(x_r-x_s)\right|^2$$
and two different complex sequences $u_r,v_r$?

> N.B.: In the assumptions there is also $\sum_r |u_r|^2=1$ but I do not think that it has some role.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing some $u_r$ in the RHS ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure! The work is: "Montgomery, H. L.; Vaughan, R. C. (1974). "Hilbert's inequality". J. London Math. Soc. (2) 8: 73–82."

Comment: In the assumptions there is also $\sum_r |u_r|^2=1$ but I do not think that it has some role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption that $\sum_r \lvert u_r\rvert^2 = 1$ does play a role. For ease of notation, let us write

$$b_r = \sum_{\substack{s\\s\neq r}} \overline{u}_s \csc \pi(x_r-x_s).$$

The left hand side of the inequality can be written as

$$\left\lvert \sum_r u_r\Biggl(\sum_{\substack{s\\ s\neq r}} \overline{u}_s \csc \pi(x_r-x_s)\Biggr)\right\rvert^2 = \left\lvert \sum_r u_r b_r\right\rvert^2.$$

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality now yields an upper bound of

$$\Biggl(\sum_r \lvert u_r\rvert^2\Biggr)\Biggl(\sum_r \lvert b_r\rvert^2\Biggr).$$

Using $\sum_r \lvert u_r\rvert^2$, the upper bound simplifies to $\sum_r \lvert b_r\rvert^2$, and expanding $b_r$ again, we get the right hand side of your inequality. (Note: on the right hand side, the constraint $s\neq r$ in the inner sum was omitted, but it must be present to get a finite right hand side, since $\csc$ has a pole at $0$.)